# UI View before camera picker view

Tags: iphone

I want to be able to display a UIAlertView and/or an actionsheet before the Camera Picker view. Is it possible and can you tell me how. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial explains it: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821

Just add a UIAlertview in the overlay view .. if you follow this tutorial, you can do it